# Compress and delete the logs in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, logrotate

I want to compress the logs older than 30 days and delete older than 90 days in shell scripting. One thing, again i ll run this script, some process i want. because of some logs will be there more 90 days in compress file. So please suggest me ..if any other concept is there , please tell me

- Kalaiyarasan

Answer (score 2):

you would want to try logrotate. It is specifically a solution for compressing, deleting after a specific interval etc.

Please check out: 
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

And there are many tutorials as well. Hopefully this point you in the right direction. Time to google. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To compress all files under the directory `/path/to/logs` that are at least 30 days old, use:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +30 -exec gzip {} +
```

To delete all files under that directory that are 90 days old or more:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +90 -delete
```

`logrotate`, as suggested by Khanna111 Gaurav is the standard tool for handling log files.  Use the above only if there is some reason that `logrotate` doesn't fit your needs.